# How do you make a query return a specific value every single time

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle SQL Developer Version 18.2.0.183, Build 183.1748 (READ ONLY ACCESS TO DB)

I am looking for a way to make a specific numerical value show up in the results of my query and then multiply that value by the result of another columns value. Here is what I got so far:

```
SELECT
DBSTAGE.AOWOD.TOQUANTITY "Quantity", 
DBSTAGE.OAWOD.TOQUANTITY ?????? "Price", 
DBSTAGE.OAWOD.TOQUANTITY * ?????? "Amount", 
DBSTAGE.OAWOM.ID "ID Number" 
FROM 
DBSTAGE.OAWOD, 
DBSTAGE.OAWOM
WHERE
DBSTAGE.AOWOM.WONUM = DBSTAGE.OAWOD.WONUM
AND DBSTAGE.AOWOM.STID = DBSTAGE.AOWOD.STID
```

This query output will will have 4 columns (Quantity, Price, Amount and ID Number). The "quantity" data format is NUMBER (5) and will always be a numerical value between 1 and 9. The "Price" data format is NUMBER (5) and will always be a numerical value and here is where I need help. I need it to always out put the price in the same numeric format of 200 on my query. You can probably guess what my next plea for help is. The "Amount" data format is NUMBER (5) and will always be a numerical value of the "Quantity" multiplied by the "Price".

DBSTAGE is the Schema
AOWOD & AOWOM are the tables
TOQUANTITY & ID are the columns on the table
Quantity, Price & Amount are the new columns in the query

Is this possible?

Thank you in advance for any help.

This is what the end results should look like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foLzc.png)

Comment: OK I Solved this portion:

DBSTAGE.OAWOD.TOQUANTITY * ?????? "Amount",

By using this

DBSTAGE.OAWOD.TOQUANTITY * 200 "Amount",

Comment: I still need help with the "Price" portion though

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result that really help

Comment: If `PRICE` is always 200 (i.e., it doesn't depend on the record in the table), then `SELECT 200 "Price" FROM...` will do what you want.

Comment: That did it A.S. K. Query now working, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some data and expected results would have been helpful in helping you. However, the answer to your question I believe is this. please note that you are using the quantity column 3 times which does seem odd to me. I think you mean to put the other column names here but i'm not certain. Also I made up a name for the price column you should replace with the correct name. Hard coding "200" in its place seems like a horrible idea to me.

```
SELECT dbstage.aowod.toquantity 
       "Quantity", 
       200 
       "Price", 
       round(dbstage.oawod.toquantity * 200, -1) 
       "Amount", 
       dbstage.oawom.id 
       "ID Number" 
FROM   dbstage.oawod, 
       dbstage.oawom 
WHERE  dbstage.aowom.wonum = dbstage.oawod.wonum 
       AND dbstage.aowom.stid = dbstage.aowod.stid
```

Comment: I am using the same column name three times because that one column has the data needed to get what I want from the other two columns I just renamed them.

EXAMPLE:

Quantity results in 2
Price always results in 200
Amount should result in 400 since that is 2 * 200 :)

Comment: can you post some test data. I'm jut not following your problem at all. It appears your  quantity column has 3 values? is that what you are saying?

Comment: Also do I need the conversion to include the decimal places since it will always be a whole number? There will never be any 1.5's or the like in Amount or Price. Would that simplify it any without that?

Comment: @Cox Please post some data. I'm and sample results.

Comment: I added a picture in the original post. Thats what I am aiming for.

That Price Column is just made up... that 115 value doesn't exist anywhere in the DB. it should actually always be 200 too. Same for the Amount column, Is made up also and is just the Quantity multiplied by the price but we already got that working.

Comment: Ok I've updated my answer Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: That's not working, It's giving me some wonky numbers... The PRICE must always equal 200 for every row of data... That's all we need working that is currently not working. The AMOUNT column works correctly as does everything else with the following ,,, DBSTAGE.OAWOD.TOQUANTITY * 200 "Amount" so we can leave the rest alone.  Just that darned PRICE that's not outputting 200.

Comment: If you want price to be a constant 200, you just use "200" in your select statement.

Comment: Ok , I've updated my answer again. if you want a constant of 200 simply just use 200 in the column. I've updated once again.